# How to Access my App's R.java file through My SDK library file?

Tags: android, sdk, r.java-file

I have a app and sdk, my sdk want to access my app's R.java file(because i need some views ID).when i try to import my
app package name along with R, like this import `com.packagename.R;`its does not accept this line, its show like `UNUSED` but i try to get the value using `findviewbyid`.
Is it possible to access my app's R.java file from SDK class file?
Guide me

```
Import packagename.R;
.
.

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(ID);
```

Comment: No, otherwise app have to supply its resources to SDK. Better way is initial sdk with `Resourses`

Comment: okay thanks , and my sdk have no resourses . . need to access App resources @Godwin

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your activity view and the component id to your SDK.
in your sdk:

```
public void initUI(View view, int editTextID) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(editTextID);
}
```

You can not reach application layer uı component id, because, think like that, there may be lots of projects that use your SDK. All project could different component with different component IDs. So at the development time, you can not reach R file of the application layer.

PS: you should null check before using a component in SDK.

Comment: yes, different component IDs but we can access via R.java file to get all the IDs right? Here i don't know the View part then how to pass view as a parameter?

Comment: create a function like initUI in your SDK project.
call this function from application project. ex: yoursdkobject.initUI(getView(), R.id.my_edit_text);

Comment: no its not working , does not get this initUI method